# Single MediaPlayer with multiple MP3s

Tags: java, android

I have a `SoundService` in my Android app that allows me to play a single audio track. Here's the service class:

```
public class UnopenedChestService extends Service {
    MediaPlayer unopenedPlayer;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    public void onCreate() {
        unopenedPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audiofile);
        unopenedPlayer.setLooping(true);
    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        unopenedPlayer.start();
        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        unopenedPlayer.stop();
        stopSelf();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

This works fine, and I can start and stop the MP3 file `audiofile` with `startService(new Intent...` and `stopService(new Intent...` respectively.

I want to add a 2nd sound that can be played in my app. I've done some digging and the only solution that came close to solving my issue was to create another `SoundService` and play a different audio file.

I did this, and it works fine.

My issue is that it feels wasteful. I have so much repeating code, and constantly stopping and starting 2 variants of `SoundService` feels hacky.

Is there a better solution than the above that would allow me to switch between MP3 files using a single `SoundService`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass parameters (song name, for example) through the intent, when starting/calling the service. In your onStartCommand you would then get those parameters (for example the name of the song) and play the selected song. This should work.